# Bash script to run random file of few specified extentions contained in current directory or its subdirectories

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have a big library of unwatched movies and sometimes when I finally find time to watch one it's hard to choose exact one. So today in order to free myself from the agony of choosing I decide to write a script. After an hour (I'm new to bash) I finally made up the solution. Here it is:

```
#fill array with relative paths to files
while IFS=  read -r -d $'\0'; do
    list+=("$REPLY")
done < <(find . -type f -iname '*.mkv' -or -print0 -iname '*.mp4' -print0 -or -iname '*.avi' -print0)

#get files number and generate random namber
numberOfFiles=${#list[@]}
randNumber=$[ 1 + $[ RANDOM % $numberOfFiles ]]

#use random number to get random file path
relativeFilePath=${list[$randNumber]}

#get rid of dot in the beginning
relativeFilePath="${relativeFilePath:1:${#relativeFilePath}-1}"

#get current dir and merge it with relative file path
filePath=${PWD}$relativeFilePath

#execute file in vlc player
vlc "$filePath"
```

The question is: how to simplify code or is it possible to do the same in other way? Personally, I don't like how file extensions are used here and feeding vlc with absolute path.

EDIT:
Suppose we have next files structure:

```
./horror/movie1.mkv
./horror/movie2.avi
./documentary/bbc/geography/asia/movie3.mkv
./sci-fi/x-man/movie4.mp4
```

So there a lot of subdirectories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU bash 4:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar nullglob
array=( **/*.{mkv,mp3} )
file="${array[${RANDOM}%${#array[@]}]}"
vlc "$file"
```

---

From `man bash`:

> `globstar`: If  set,  the  pattern ** used in a pathname expansion context will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories. If the pattern is followed by a /, only  directories  and subdirectories match.
>
> `nullglob`: If set, bash allows patterns which match no files (see Pathname Expansion) to expand to a null string, rather than themselves.

Answer (score 2):

The following will open a random file from the current directory (or subdirectories) with vlc (we assume you have no non-video files in your video collection):

```
vlc $(find -type f | shuf | head -n 1)
```

If you have non-video files, we get slightly smarter:

```
vlc $(find -type f -iname '*.mp4' -o -iname '*.mkv' | shuf | head -n 1)
```

(And you can see how to add more extensions)

Comment: When I run this command in directory with video files it works but not all the time, mostly it fails with error "Cannot open file"